# How do you check if a specific user reacts to a specific message [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've looked at similar questions but none of the answers worked for me. I'm working on a bot where you type in `(prefix)suggest (suggestion)` and then it sends a message asking if you are sure you want to send the suggestion. If they react to that message with the reaction that the bot has added (check mark) then it sends the suggestion to a channel.

In short, how do I create a trigger where if a specific person reacts to a specific message with a specific emoji then it sends the output?

Answer (score 5):

To make it reaction check message specific you need to use `reaction.message == message` in the check function.

Here's the full example based on Libby's answer.

```py
message = await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to submit this suggestion?")
await message.add_reaction("✅")

def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅"] and reaction.message == message
confirmation = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check) 
channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Put suggestion channel ID here.

if confirmation:
    await channel.send(suggestion)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wait_for` function to make the bot wait until the author reacts with the checkmark.

First, do a check to ensure that the bot sends the suggestion to the suggestion channel only if **the message author reacts with a checkmark:**

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅"]
```

Then put the code that sends the confirmation message and has the `wait_for` function:

```
message = await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to submit this suggestion?")
await message.add_reaction("✅")
confirmation = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check) 
channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Put suggestion channel ID here.
```

Finally, put the code that tells the bot what to do once the message author reacts:

```
if confirmation:
    await channel.send(suggestion)
```

Comment: The problem is that bot will still do something even if user added reaction to some other message, not to the one that bot sent.