# Rock Paper Scissor Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was trying to make a rock paper scissor command on my discord.py bot but instead of sending responses you use  reactions but rn the responds to its own reactions. Tried The code is

````
    async def rps(self, ctx):
        global RPS_START, RPS_AUTHOR, channel
        channel = ctx.channel
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**Rock Paper Scissor**")
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('✂')
        RPS_START = True
        RPS_AUTHOR = ctx.message.author

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, reaction):
        global RPS_START, RPS_AUTHOR, human_decision, channel, reply
        if RPS_START is False and reaction.member != RPS_AUTHOR and not reaction.member.bot:
            return
        elif reaction.emoji.name == '':
            human_decision = 'rock'
        elif reaction.emoji.name == '':
            human_decision = 'paper'
        elif reaction.emoji.name == '✂':
            human_decision = 'scissor'
        RPS_START = False

        rock_paper_scissors = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
        bot_decision = (random.choice(rock_paper_scissors)).lower()

        if human_decision in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']:
            if human_decision == bot_decision:
                reply = 'tie'
            elif human_decision == 'rock' and bot_decision == 'paper':
                reply = 'lost'
            elif human_decision == 'paper' and bot_decision == 'rock':
                reply = 'win'
            elif human_decision == 'scissor' and bot_decision == 'paper':
                reply = 'win'
            elif human_decision == 'paper' and bot_decision == 'scissor':
                reply = 'lost'
            elif human_decision == 'stone' and bot_decision == 'scissor':
                reply = 'win'
            elif human_decision == 'scissor' and bot_decision == 'rock':
                reply = 'lost'```
````

Comment: In the future, you may not want to use the `on_raw_reaction_add` event. The problem is that if multiple users use the command at the same time, there will most definitely be problems. Instead, I recommend using `checks` like the following: [Reaction Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091055/14420546), [How do you check if a specific user reacts to a specific message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088455/14420546), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change:

```py
if RPS_START is False and payload.member.id != RPS_AUTHOR and payload.member.bot:
      return
```

To:

```py
if RPS_START is False or payload.member.id != RPS_AUTHOR or payload.member.bot:
      return
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple if statement at the beggining of your `on_raw_reaction_add` event should fix the problem:

```
if reaction.member.bot:
    return
```

Also you can get really confused when using `reaction` as a name of your variable. In the docs it is declared as `payload` so you should consider changing it.

Comment: Didn't fix it bot still replies but only once tho before it reacted multiple time