# Check if user react with an certian emoji with cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. How can I check which emoji the user reacted with? That did not work for me [How do you check if a specific user reacts to a specific message [discord.py]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171531/how-do-you-check-if-a-specific-user-reacts-to-a-specific-message-discord-py)

I want to check if the reaction is `✅` or `❌`

folder structure

```
├── main.py
├── cogs
│   ├── member.py
```

The problem is that I don't get an error message. Nothing happens. As soon as I react with an emoji, nothing happens.

member.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

class command(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
            ...
                 ...
                    for emoji in emojis:
                        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)



                    await message.author.send('Send me that ✅ reaction, mate')

                    def check(reaction, user):
                        return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

                    res = await self.bot.wait_for(
                        "reaction_add",
                        check=check, timeout=None
                    )
                    print(res.emoji)

                    if res.content.lower() == "✅":
                        await message.author.send("Got it")
                    else:
                        await message.author.send("Thanks")
                    
                    confirmation = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
                    await message.author.send("You responded with {}".format(reaction.emoji))


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(command(bot))
```

```py
import asyncio
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

import discord
from discord.utils import get

  
    
class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('-'), intents=intents, max_messages=1000)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if file.endswith(".py"):
                extension = file[:-3]
                try:
                    await self.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
                    print(f"Loaded extension '{extension}'")
                except Exception as e:
                    exception = f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}"
                    print(f"Failed to load extension {extension}\n{exception}")

bot = MyBot()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. For example, does this need to be in a cog to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a function called `check`, and it doesn't exist - like your error is telling you. There's one in your class, but that isn't in the same scope so you can't just call it using its name.

To access a method in a class, use `self.<name>`.

Also, you should only *pass the check function*, not *call* it.

```py
(..., check=self.check
```

**EDIT** the code in the original question was edited. You're not loading your cogs asynchronously. Extensions & cogs were made async in 2.0. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Comment: Thank you very much. But nothing happend. :/. The method is not executed

Comment: If you print something in the check, do you see it? Also you're loading cogs incorrectly so chances are the cog is just not even loaded. Cog loading is async now, you should adapt your code to that. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I changed it, please see my edit. Unfortunately I got the following error `AttributeError: __aenter__`.

Comment: I'd recommend you go the ``setup_hook`` route instead of the context manager (``async_with``) as it's a bit easier for beginners & then you don't have to configure logging. Make an instance of that MyBot class & start it with .run()

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my answer. But unfourtanly I does not load the extensions. Only the "Logged in as..." print is shown...

Comment: Are you sure that the paths are correct? You have a print if it succeeds and a print if it errors. Either the for-loop doesn't find anything, or setup_hook doesn't even run. Both of these can be easily checked with a few prints. What dpy version are you on?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the method `setup_hook` is not executed at all. `discord.py==2.1.0` and `py-cord==2.2.2`. Before that, all the paths worked perfectly.

Comment: Why do you have pycord? That's why it doesn't work, it's breaking your dpy install. Uninstall every discord-related library and re-install only dpy.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. The problem is still that this method `reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)` is not executed. The bot `message.author.send` still sends a message, but nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: If I set a print within the method `check` it is not executed.

Comment: Please see my edit. The error only occurs as soon as I write something new. If I add a recation, nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure why you made a lambda instead of a regular function but okay. The error tells you what's wrong. You made a lambda that takes 1 argument, but when the library calls it it gets 2. `on_reaction_add` takes a reaction and a user, so it should have two arguments instead of one. Also, `x.author.id` wouldn't work because it doesn't contain an `author` attribute. That's why you get a second argument, being the user that added it. The example in the docs clearly shows this... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed it. But nothing happend :/. f I add a recation, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `@commands.Cog.listener()` decorator, and the code will work if your cogs loader is working. If you would like me to show you my cogs loader, I can.

```py
accept = '✅'
decline = ''

def check(reaction, user):
  return user == author

messsage = await ctx.send("test")
await message.add_reaction(accept)
await message.add_reaction(decline)

reaction = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)

if str(reaction[0]) == accept:
  await ctx.send("Accepted")
elif str(reaction[0]) == decline:
  await ctx.send("Denied")
```